# Access child records in non-nested routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

If I have an "organization" that has many "clinics" and in my app I don't want the routes nested, but I want to access the clinics on an organization page and the organization on a clinic page, is there something special I need to do? I am using rails as a backend and if I switch from the RestAdapter to the ActiveModelAdapter and embed the clinic ids it works, but I would like to know how to do it with the standard RestAdapter.

**Router:**

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'organizations', ->
  @resource 'organization', path: 'organization/:organization_id', ->

  @resource 'clinics', ->
```

**Organization template:**

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<h2>Clinics</h2>
  {{#link-to 'clinics.new'}}New Clinic{{/link-to}}
<ul id="org-clinics">
  {{#each clinics}}
    <li>{{#link-to 'clinic' this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{else}}
    <strong>No clinics yet...</strong>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

**Organization model:**

```
App.Organization = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  clinics: DS.hasMany 'clinic', async: true
```

**Clinic template:**

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<strong>Organization: </strong>{{organization.name}}
```

**Clinic model:**

```
App.Clinic = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  organization: DS.belongsTo 'organization'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you want to go about it, but you can bind controller content super easily. For example:

```
App.OrganizationsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['clinics'],
  clinics: null,
  clinicsBinding, 'controllers.clinics.content',

  clinicsUpdated: function () {
    // Do something here because some record updated
  }.observes('clinics.@each.content') // Bind properties
});

App.ClinicsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['organizations'],
  organizations: null,
  organizationsBinding, 'controllers.organizations.content'
});
```

You can acess them in templates, too. For example, `{{#each clinics}}`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey again Matthew! Thanks for the help. I have a create clinic form, and when I create the clinic and redirect back to the organization page, the clinic doesn't show up until there is a refresh? Is it due to the same problem that the observe would fix?

Comment: Hey, happy to help! Are you specifying the organization during the clinic creation? I think it would be best to start a new question that focuses solely on something like "When I create a record it doesn't render until I refresh." Then show your current organization route, controller, and template bits that are relevant. Same goes for the clinic creation. I or someone else can definitely help from there!

Comment: Right on. I will do that.